# How to revert a test account to a normal account on Facebook

Tags: facebook

I want to start developing some Facebook applications and I came across this page that allows me to create a test account.

**Please do not click the `Make [Your Name] Test Account`**
[Become a Platform App Test Account](http://www.facebook.com/developers/become_test_account.php)
[image: Test Account Page]

I went against my urge to click and decided to google a bit and it seems this option converts your actual Facebook account into a  test account.

How can one revert this change ?

Comment: This [link](http://www.facebook.com/developers/become_test_account.php) of converting "existing" facebook account into test account no longer works.
How can i convert any existing account into test account for development.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does indeed convert your "normal" account to a "test" account and **it cannot be reversed**

Take a look at [this Article](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users/) on Facebook:

> We ensure that test users are exempt
>   from Facebook spam or fake account
>   detection systems to ensure that you
>   can test your application without
>   worrying about getting disabled.
>
> Also, to ensure that using test user
>   accounts to test various scenarios
>   doesn't end up unintentionally
>   creating spam, we enforce certain
>   limitations on what test users can do.
>
> - Test users can interact with other test users only and not with real
>     users on site.
> - Test users cannot fan a public Page or create public content on them like
>     writing on a Page's wall. A Test user
>     can however view and interact with the
>     application tab on the Page if they
>     are associated with that app.
> - They can be accessed and used by any developer of the associated
>     application.
> - They only have test privileges on the associated application. This
>     implies that they can use the app in
>     live mode or sandbox mode but cannot
>     edit any technical settings or access
>     insights for that application.
> - A test user is always a test user and cannot be converted to a normal
>     user account.

Up until yesterday, creating a Test Account used to just add you to the Facebook Test Network. So to undo this, all you had to do previously was remove yourself from the Test Network.  Unfortunately, this is no longer true due to recent changes made by Facebook.

There is a [blog post here](http://www.skybondsor.com/blog/undo-test-account-on-facebook) with further information about this.

**UPDATE**

The process of converting your own account to a test account is now redundant.

> You can now create up to 50 developer test accounts to interact with
>   your apps. Developers will be able to use the Graph API to create
>   accounts, manage friends, test their apps, and build automated tests.
>   These new tests accounts do not need to be verified, & each test user
>   will receive a login URL that does not require a password. More
>   detailed documentation of the APIs is available [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users/).

Test accounts can now be created via the Graph API.

> A test user is a user account associated with an app created for the
>   purpose of testing the functionality of that app. You can use test
>   users for manual or automated testing.
>
> We allow you to access the test account via a login_url which allows
>   you to directly login to the account. The login_url expires after one
>   hour, but you easily refresh it to get a new login_url for the same
>   test user. We also provide you an access_token for the test user so
>   that you can take actions on behalf of the test user via the api.
>
> An app can create up to 500 test users to start testing an app.